# Is it possible to add markup for p:menubutton to p:tabview's navigation panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to somehow place the JSF markup for a menubutton inside a `tabview`'s navigation panel(where tabs are listed), so that I can have a list of tabs as a dropdown besides other tabs listed normally in the tabview ? I use primefaces with JSF 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try simply overlapping the p:menubutton on top of tabview navigation panel. Use z-index higher than that of tabview.